# What are Acceptable Small Mounts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, races, mount

In my current *Pathfinder* campaign, I have been playing as a Gnome Cavalier that has earned enough experience to level up for the first time AND has successfully reared a wild Vulture. One of the feats that has caught my eye is the [Undersized Mount](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/undersized-mount-combat) feat. Through technicality, my character (being small) could ride on the back of an other small creature (like my Vulture) if this feat was taken. However, I wish to be as close to RAW as possible, and have not been able to find any mounts smaller than Medium. As such, I feel that I must ask this; **Is there such a thing as a Small Mount, or would it be useless for a Small Character to take *Undersized Mount*?**

Comment: I don't understand your question: you first mention that you know you could ride your small-sized vulture (using the feat), but then you ask if there are small-sized creatures that can be ridden (to make the feat useful). How does your question not answer itself?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think the distinction being made is between "every small creature that could theoretically be a mount" and "small creatures that are officially mounts". Whether that distinction is a meaningful one I suspect would be the main point of an answer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie he's looking for official material that specifices the existence of *some* small mount (I suspect he's trying to justify that the technicality in the Undersized Mount feat was intended by the authors and not just some weirdness that should rightly be rule 0'ed into oblivion.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Small mounts exist in official material

[PFSRD entry on Ride](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/ride) lists a great number of creatures suitable to be mounts (though the list isn't exhaustive) and some of them are Small. While indeed the majority of them are Medium or larger, you can find Small mounts that would perfectly justify a Small character taking Undersized Mount feat.

In fact, right there at the end of the list, in Other Animals section, you can find that Vulture is an animal suited to be ridden and indeed small. Go ahead and show it to your GM, the list specifies increased costs and that some rare vendors might even provide a combat trained Vulture!

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Now if you can excuse me, I would like to figure out an equipment load-out that my vulture could support